# cron jobs still executing after it is remove in directadmin panel

Tags: linux, cron

I have problem on cron jobs that are still executing even after removing them.
I already view [all the possible cron jobs from this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-what-cron-jobs-are-setup/). All cron config files are empty or my cron task are not present. I also came up with this command [`for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users). And it returns no crontab set for all users.

Are there other ways to check currrently executing cron jobs?

Comment: just in case someone needs, I just check on the current running processes on the server. In my case ps ax. then i killed the cron task. hope this would help..

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have restarted cron daemon before you find your task is still executing.

Have you also install Anacron?

> anacron is a computer program that performs periodic command scheduling which is traditionally done by cron, but without assuming that the system is running continuously.

Its configuration file is  /etc/anacrontab.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit cron jobs, you need to restart cron deamon.

```
service cron restart
```

I hope you doing it long time ago.